# How to save score and restart app to start page in Android?

Tags: android

I'm new to Android Studio and I have a little problem with a quiz application.

Right now whenever I finish my quiz I have two options:

- To see the total score view or
- To retry playing the game

When I click total score the total score is shown correctly(sum of all the score until now including the current score). However when I click `retry` I can't manage to add the current score to the total score. Any hint would be great.

Code for the `retry` button:

```
 builder.setPositiveButton("Retry", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Result.class);//in this view 
       //the total score is //computed
                intent.putExtra("RIGHT_ANS_COUNT",rightAnsCount); 
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
                Intent intent1=new  Intent(getApplicationContext(),Start.class);
                startActivity(intent1);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try using shared preferences to store the total score and you can retrieve the score when the game is retried. You can learn about shared preferences from the official Android [Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences). And if I may ask, why are you starting starting another intent after finishing the activity?